# Use only the value from IO monad without precedent IO actions

Tags: scala, io, monads, scalaz

Doing some home project, I encountered an interested effect, which now , seems obvious to me, but still I do not see a way to get away from it.
That is the gist (I am using ScalaZ, but in haskell there would be probably the same result):

```
def askAndReadResponse(question: String): IO[String] = {
  putStrLn(question) >> readLn
}

def core: IO[String] = {
  val answer: IO[String] = askAndReadResponse("enter something")
  val cond: IO[Boolean] = answer map {_.length > 2}
  IO.ioMonad.ifM(cond, answer, core)
}
```

When I am trying to get an input from `core`, the `askAndReadResponse` evaluates twice  - once for evaluating the condition, and then in `ifM` (so I have the message and `readLn` one more time then necessary).
What I need - just the validated value (to print it later, for instance)

Is there any elegant way to do this, in particular - to pass further the result of IO, without preceding IO actions, namely avoiding execution of  `askAndReadResponse` twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sequence the effects using monadic binding with `flatMap`:

```
def core: IO[String] = askAndReadResponse("enter something").flatMap {
  case response if response.length > 2 => response.point[IO]
  case response => core
}
```

This lets you take the result of one computation (the user entering text after being prompted) and use it in subsequent computations (the calculation about whether to return or loop, and the result if returning).

`ifM` just isn't going to be useful in your case—it would only work here if your condition and your successful branch were independent computations.

Comment: Thanks, that works! It seems that  #ifM is to be used for completely different purposes